# Como itearar en una tabla con 2 for (calumna) (fila)?

Tags: javascript, bucles

Estoy intentando sacar 2 `td` de una tabla y pasalo a una variable (**i** y **j**) y luego otra variable con el `getElementById`.

Mirar el codigo:

Tengo un botón que al hacer *clic* me rellena 2 **input** con 2 celdas de una tabla. La pregunta es ¿cómo puedo crear un **for** para **i** y un **for** para **j** (`.rows[i].cells[j]`), para poder recogerlo y maandarlo al input con la funcion `cambiarValor`?

Intenté hacerlo **1x1** pero no puede. Creo que la única solución es un **for** dentro de otro o si alguien me puede sugerir una idea mejor.

Muchas Gracias de antemano

Código:

```js
var td11 = document.getElementById("table").rows[1].cells[1];
console.log(td11.innerText);

var td12 = document.getElementById("table").rows[1].cells[2];
console.log(td12.innerText);

// cargar valor en input
function cambiarValor() {
  document.getElementById('ciudad').value = td11.innerText;
  document.getElementById("fecha").value = td12.innerText;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr class="tr0">
    <td></td>
    <td>Ciudades</td>
    <td>Fechas</td>
    <td>Comprar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01</td>
    <td class="ciudad">Madrid</td>
    <td class="fecha" name="fecha">01/07/2022</td>
    <td>
      <ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping" onclick="cambiarValor(), irmarcador('comprar')"> </ion-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>02</td>
    <td class="ciudad">Malaga</td>
    <td class="fecha">04/07/22</td>
    <td>
      <ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping" onclick="cambiarValor()"> </ion-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr1">
    <td>03</td>
    <td class="ciudad">Valencia</td>
    <td class="fecha">05/07/22</td>
    <td>
      <ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping" onclick="cambiarValor()"> </ion-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>04</td>
    <td class="ciudad">Canarias</td>
    <td class="fecha">06/07/22</td>
    <td>
      <ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping" onclick="cambiarValor()"> </ion-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr1">
    <td>05</td>
    <td class="ciudad">Tenerife</td>
    <td class="fecha">07/07/22</td>
    <td>
      <ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping" onclick="cambiarValor()"> </ion-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>06</td>
    <td class="ciudad">Toldedo</td>
    <td class="fecha">09/07/22</td>
    <td>
      <ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping" onclick="cambiarValor()"> </ion-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr1">
    <td>07</td>
    <td class="ciudad">Granada</td>
    <td class="fecha">11/07/22</td>
    <td>
      <ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping" onclick="cambiarValor()"> </ion-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>08</td>
    <td class="ciudad">Palma</td>
    <td class="fecha">13/07/22</td>
    <td>
      <ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping" onclick="cambiarValor()"> </ion-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr1">
    <td>09</td>
    <td class="ciudad">Bilbao</td>
    <td class="fecha">15/07/22</td>
    <td>
      <ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping" onclick="cambiarValor()"> </ion-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td class="ciudad">Barcelona</td>
    <td class="fecha">18/07/22</td>
    <td>
      <ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping" onclick="cambiarValor()"> </ion-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas obtener cada botón y asignarle evento. Puedes "delegarlo" a la tabla, de forma que creas solo una función que se encargue de revisar dónde se hizo el clic.

Si se hizo en un botón, entonces accedes a la fila a la que pertenece y, desde ahí, obtienes la información de las celdas relacionadas. Revisa los comentarios para ver qué hace cada sentencia.

**Importante:** Eliminé el atributo *onclick* de cada botón, porque no es necesario, ni conveniente.

```js
// Asignar evento a tabla
document.querySelector('#table').addEventListener('click', e => {
    // e es el evento
    // e.target es el elemento que lo disparó
    if(e.target.classList.contains('shopping')) {
        // El clic fue en un icono
        let shopping = e.target;
        // Desde el icono se puede obtener la fila con closest()
        let tr = e.target.closest('tr');
        // Ahora puedes acceder a cada celda
        let ciudad = tr.cells[1].innerText;
        let fecha = tr.cells[2].innerText;
        // Ahora puedes hacer lo que necesites con estos valores
        console.log(ciudad, fecha);
        // Aquí puedes cambiar el valor de los campos
    }
});
```

```css
.shopping {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <tr class="tr0">
        <td></td>
        <td>Ciudades</td>
        <td>Fechas</td>
        <td>Comprar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td class="ciudad">Madrid</td>
        <td class="fecha" name="fecha">01/07/2022</td>
        <td><ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping"></ion-icon></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>02</td>
        <td class="ciudad">Malaga</td>
        <td class="fecha">04/07/22</td>
        <td><ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping"></ion-icon></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr1">
        <td>03</td>
        <td class="ciudad">Valencia</td>
        <td class="fecha">05/07/22</td>
        <td><ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping"></ion-icon></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>04</td>
        <td class="ciudad">Canarias</td>
        <td class="fecha">06/07/22</td>
        <td><ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping"></ion-icon></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr1">
        <td>05</td>
        <td class="ciudad">Tenerife</td>
        <td class="fecha">07/07/22</td>
        <td><ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping"></ion-icon></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>06</td>
        <td class="ciudad">Toldedo</td>
        <td class="fecha">09/07/22</td>
        <td><ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping"></ion-icon></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr1">
        <td>07</td>
        <td class="ciudad">Granada</td>
        <td class="fecha">11/07/22</td>
        <td><ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping"></ion-icon></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>08</td>
        <td class="ciudad">Palma</td>
        <td class="fecha">13/07/22</td>
        <td><ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping"></ion-icon></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr1">
        <td>09</td>
        <td class="ciudad">Bilbao</td>
        <td class="fecha">15/07/22</td>
        <td><ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping"></ion-icon></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td class="ciudad">Barcelona</td>
        <td class="fecha">18/07/22</td>
        <td><ion-icon name="cart-outline" class="shopping"></ion-icon></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, que facil lo haces XD, llevaba 2 días en esto